# How to know unordered_map<T*> contains a value?

Tags: c++

I have a class node:

```
class node{
  public:
  int x,y;
  // some other variables
};
```

Somewhere else there is an `unordered_map<node*,node*>`. How can I find a particular node in the map? Two nodes are considered equals if `node_a.x==node_b.x && node_a.y==node_b.y`. The `unordered_map.find` method finds if the **pointer to the node** is found but I need to find a node in map that is equal to my node in x and y.

The reason I have map to pointer is that **node** is not a trivial class and have other member variable so using `unordered_map<node,node>` is out of question.

Comment: Note: You might replace `unordered_map<node*,node*>`  by `unordered_set<node*>`. But likely you want an `unordered_map<point,node*>`.

Comment: Look at [`KeyEqual`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) template parameter

Comment: _`unordered_map<node*,node*>`_ looks like a serious design flaw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have control of the map construction as the other answer suggests then the following is a potential solution (untested, may require small tweaks):

```
std::unordered_map<node*,node*> map;
//...
// node object to find
node n;
n.x = 0;
n.y = 0;
std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), 
    [n](const std::pair<node*,node*>& _node) 
    -> bool { return _node.first->x == n.x && _node.second->y == n.y; });
```

Note, however, that `std::unordered_map<node*,node*>` is a strange construct and I would strongly advise you to reconsider this data structure based on what your requirements actually are.

Comment: Nice, simple and fast solution using lambdas and custom comparators, I like it. And I agree that OP probably is using the wrong data structure for whatever he intends to do. The only thing missing is check for null pointers (if they are possible), at least with asserts. That's what I would do anyway.

Answer (score 2):

From your reasoning it is unclear why you still cannot use `unordered_map<node, node>`.

But since you are determined to store pointers yet perform value comparisons, your only option is container-wide linear search, `std::find_if` for instance.

Comment: Well, doesn't call a construct like `unordered_map<node, node>` rather for using a `unordered_set<node>` actually?

Comment: We don't know the exact key-value correspondence in op's question. There is no evidence key is always the same as value.

Comment: We don't know about that much anyways here, unless that's a big thrill and shudder, crying out **don't do that**.

Comment: The reason for having pointers is I have an object pool and these nodes are fetched and returned to the pool. There are hundreds of thousands of them present  at a given time. So They need to be present on the heap and also nodes are heavywight objects having vector and list within them. so it is not feasible to have unorderdmap<node,node> and copy them to map freely.

Answer (score 2):

If you control the construction of this map, you can give it an equality function and hash function that is consistent with that definition of equals:

```
auto hash_fun = [] (node* obj) { return /* some hash value computed from x and y */; };
auto key_equal = [] (node* a, node* b) { return a->x == b->x && a->y == b->y; };
typedef std::unordered_map<node*,node*,decltype(hash_fun),decltype(key_equal)> node_map;
node_map map(0, hash_fun, key_equal);
```

Comment: You need to alter the template parameters too.

Comment: Yes I create the map

Comment: It cannot be done through this specific syntax, since that way you cannot specify the comparator type in template parameter list. Wanna use lambdas - store them in variables in advance and use `decltype` in template argument list.

Comment: It gives compile error no instance of constructor "std::unordered_map<_Kty, _Ty, _Hasher, _Keyeq, _Alloc>::unordered_map [with _Kty=node *, _Ty=node *, _Hasher=std::hash<node *>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<node *>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<node *const, node *>>]" matches the argument list  e:\Game\projects\TerraGod\TerraGodLibCPP\PpaGraph.cpp 36

Comment: @AnT and T.C. fixed, thanks for the tip. I'm too polluted by Java at work nowadays ;)